# Select some columns and a count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to select two columns in a table and a count of associated rows from another.
Basically, I got two tables:

Table `rem` :

```
rem_id (Int, AI, Index) | rem_name (Varchar)
```

Table `map` :

```
rem_id (Int, AI, Index) | data (Text)
```

I want to get the two columns of the table `rem` and how many data entries are stored for each row.

I've tried to use the following query, but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT
    rem_id,
    rem_name,
    COUNT(
         SELECT map.rem_id
         FROM map
         WHERE map.rem_id = rem.rem_id)
FROM rem;
```

I'm under Postgresql 9.3

Could you pleas help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT rem.rem_id,
       rem.rem_name,
       COUNT(map.rem_id) as cnt
FROM rem
LEFT JOIN map ON map.rem_id = rem.rem_id
GROUP BY rem.rem_id, rem.rem_name
```

Use a `left join` to connect the tables, group by the `rem` columns and then you can count for each `rem` record.

Comment: Ha, you beat me to it! :)

Comment: Should be group by `rem.rem_id` to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rem_id,rem_name,(SELECT COUNT(map.rem_id) FROM map
WHERE map.rem_id = rem.rem_id) FROM rem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've basically three options.

The default goto query would be:

```
SELECT rem.rem_id,
       rem.rem_name,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM rem
LEFT JOIN map ON map.rem_id = rem.rem_id
GROUP BY rem.rem_id, rem.rem_name
```

Think of it as the yardstick.

Semantically, the latter is roughly equivalent to the same query using a window function:

```
SELECT rem.rem_id,
       rem.rem_name,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rem.rem_id) as cnt
FROM rem
LEFT JOIN map ON map.rem_id = rem.rem_id
```

Window functions are mostly useful when you need to create what amounts to multiple group by clauses (using `partition by`) on the same set.

A correlated subquery works will usually perform a bit better *in cases where a limited number of rows is pre-selected*:

```
SELECT rem.rem_id,
       rem.rem_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM map WHERE map.rem_id = rem.rem_id) as cnt
FROM rem
ORDER BY rem.ren_name LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 -- As an example
```

The third and last option is to maintain a `cnt` column in `rem`, and maintain it using triggers on `map`. In that case you'd simply select that extra column. This is the best approach in terms of performance. In fact, it is the only reasonable one if you plan to actually order by `cnt`.

Comment: you can also use `count()` as a window function to remove the required use of the `group by`